# How can Kurento use Opencv 3.0

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, kurento

I am working on a project needs using Opencv 3.0 or higher. But it seems kurento only supports for Opencv 2.4 which seems too old for me.

I follows all the steps to create my custom Kurento module, it comes an error like below when kurento want to load this module.

*Module libopencvpluginsample.so cannot be loaded: libopencvpluginsample.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2cv6String10deallocateEv*

Comment: "seems too old for me" -- The latest [release](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/releases) on the 2.4.x branch is only about a week older than the latest on the 3.x branch... | Why does your project require the 3.x branch?

Comment: Cause my team members made a library of this project using opencv 3.x branch.  Since kurento use Opencv 2.0.0 version, it does not has such Opencv 3.x symbols.

Comment: Ya, that is rather obvious. Why did your team choose 3.x? Are you using modules or functionality not present in 2.4.x? Which one? What are the showstoppers to backporting your code to version of OpenCV that Kurento uses? I would assume that in most cases it would be easier for your team to port and test the code you wrote, rather than a substantial third party library. Trying to mix two versions of the same library would be my last resort.

Comment: @ZhehengSong: May I ask if you could solve this problem?